# Chrome extension actions on next tab and back to previous tab

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want change tab to next one, do some actions on HTML (like get some data) there, then back to 'main' tab. Two tabs always are opened. I can change tab (using background.js) it should be active but when i try get html it always get background.html... is there any way to get html code from 2nd tab? I think i can also do 'back to previous tab' so what i really need: **get html from 2nd tab**! (if its possible, where i can do actions on html?)

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "name",
  "description": "desc.",
  "version": "1.0",

"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"content_scripts" :[
{
  "matches":[
    "http://www.thecrims.com/*"
  ],
  "js":["contentscript.js"]
}
],

"permissions": [
  "http://www.thecrims.com/*",
  "https://www.thecrims.com/*",
  "background",
  "tabs"
],
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.jpg"
}
}
```

call from **contentscript.js** to background.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

console.log(sender.tab ?
            "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
            "from the extension");
if (request.greeting == "hello")
{
    chrome.windows.getLastFocused(
         // Without this, window.tabs is not populated.
         {populate: true},
         function (window)
         {
          var foundSelected = false;
          for (var i = 0; i < window.tabs.length; i++)
          {
           // Finding the selected tab.
           if (window.tabs[i].active)
           {
            foundSelected = true;
           }
           // Finding the next tab.
           else if (foundSelected)
           {
            // Selecting the next tab.
            chrome.tabs.update(window.tabs[i].id, {active: true, selected: true});

            //GET HTML FROM ^
            chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs) {
                console.log(tabs[0]);//this give me BACKGROUND.HTML html... i want from tabs[0]!!
            });

            return;
           }
          }
         });
  sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're trying to run this from the Dev Tools for your background page open.

Then the active window (as queried by `tabs.query`) would be exactly that, the Dev Tools window with a single tab.

Why are you even running the `query`? You already have the tab in `window.tabs[i]`, use that instead of `tabs[0]`.

Comment: Well... i'm running the `query` cause i dont really know how to use `window.tabs[i]`. lets say i need *click button on 2nd tab* (on `window.tab[i]`) i should use `executeScript`? like `chrome.tabs.executeScript(window.tab[i], code:{<button_click>}, function(result){});`? btw. is it possible to do action on 2nd tab (window.tab[i]) without changing tab? i mean without changing to `active: true, selected: true`